# Migration on-premise Postgresql into AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql-9.5, aws-dms

I work on migration on-premise postgresql 9.5 server into RDS. Basically the chain I have come out look like this:

[pg master on-premise] -> [pg slave on-premise] -> [aws dms replication instance] -> [aws rds postgresql]

Note that:

1. The replication between pg master and pg slave was set as "hot_standby" mode.
2. I try to daisy chain (or cascade replication in postgresql term) connection on pg slave due to performance and high availability concerns.
3. From pg slave on-prem to aws replication instance, as AWS documentation suggested, that I have to set the replication mode as "logical".
4. Changing all replication mode to "logical" should be the last consideration.

Just wonder if this kind of half-half (half-hotstandby-half-logical) would work. If that works, what kind of stuffs I need to pay special attention with. And, if that won't work, what alternative ways you would suggest.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the solution purposed works. But there's a spin-off issue: either my data have problem in the middle of the journey, or DMS does not support jsonb format.